# Why does Spring SAML SP need a keystore and related key configuration?

Tags: spring-saml, spring-security-saml2

I have a spring boot application and planning to use Okta, referring to the below 2 samples, what is the purpose of configuring keystore for service provider?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/blob/master/samples/spring-security-saml-dsl-sample/src/main/java/com/example/SecurityConfiguration.java

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-saml-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/SecurityConfiguration.java

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in SAML 2.0 specs [[http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf]](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf),

> All SAML protocol request and response messages MAY be signed using XML Signature

That means your Service Provider could have the need to sign his requests.